# asp.net mvc global vs class filters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter

My MVC 3 app has authorize filters at the class level. As I understand it, when I try for example /Home/Index and I have not logged in it should re-route me to the page I have specified - my log-in page.

My app does not do this and I am allowed to see the result of Home/Index having not logged in; However, when I register the filters globally, the authorization step kicks in as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by class level authorize filters? If you place it on the controller it will work and apply to all action on this particular controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Now if you try to navigate to `/Home/Index` and the user is not logged in he will be redirected to the LogOn action.